# text fade out based on element content

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is my JS:

```
if($('.js-documentBox').length){
    $('.js-documentBox').each(function(){
        if($(this).text().length > 20){
            $(this).addClass('test-class');
        }
    });
}
```

This is my html:

```
<span class="js-documentBox">6227_150510_0510175608II</span>
```

So, first I am check if element with '.js-documentBox' exists and then for each found element I am check if it's content is more than 20 characters, if it is true I am adding 'test-class'. The problem is than in test-class I want css which will make the same effect as this code:

```
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Any suggestions how to get the same effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `display:inline-block;` to test-class:

```
.test-class {
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   display:inline-block;
   width:150px;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Just tried it - you should also use `width` otherwise you'll not see the effect

heres my fiddle [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/4cr87bng/)

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/onxLuhwj/ how to fix this alignment problem the elements have different heights

Comment: add     float:left;  to test-class - i updated your fiddle.

[link](http://fiddle.jshell.net/onxLuhwj/1/)

Answer (score 1):

[`text-overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) only applies to block level elements (spans are inline by default), so you'd need to either make the spans into divs (or other block level element) or change it's styling to include something like `display:block`.

Comment: If you post a fiddle demonstrating what you have now, I can modify it to show you what to change.